# Help reworking a sentence to make it less ambigious

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

Are there any rules governing what the "which" refers to in a sentence like this:

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts a JSON document to
>   my CouchDB instance which looks like:

Above, the meaning of "which" was meant to refer to the "JSON document", but I feel that people might interpret it as referring to "CouchDB instance".

I would like to retain the active voice, but feel like rewording it is *awkward*:

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts a JSON document, that looks as follows, to my CouchDB instance:

UPDATE: What follows the colon is an example JSON document like:

```
 { foo: bar,
   key: 2
  }
```

Comment: Just an example of code that represents the document.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm not sure I get it :-(

Comment: I'd go with yours @KateGregory, if only you were to post it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it two sentences. Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts a JSON document to my CouchDB instance. The document looks like this:

```
{ 
  foo: bar,
  key: 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application sends the following JSON document to my CouchDB

You could also write the number 5 instead of "five". It makes a better impact, at least to me. I'd also try to make it shorter, so something like this would also work, if you are less meticulous.

> Every 5 mins, the Node.js app sends the following JSON to my CouchDB

Answer (score 0):

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts the following JSON document to my CouchDB instance:

Or, if that's an example and not exactly what will be posted:

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts a JSON document like the following to my CouchDB instance:

Answer (score 0):

One could move up the "to my CouchDB instance" phrase:

> Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts to my CouchDB instance a JSON document as follows:

```
    { foo: bar, key: 2
    }
```

I think this concisely fixes the ambiguity problem.
A remaining drawback of the above form is that it has no good place for an end-of-sentence period.  If that's a problem you can't abide, change "as follows:" to "as shown below.".

Comment: Both “…as follows” and “the following…” are fine with a period instead of a colon, I think. It’s just that a colon is perhaps more common.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "rules" in play here. Without context, the construction is inherently ambiguous.

I'm sure it doesn't really matter though. In the *actual* context, something will follow the colon. Anyone who can't instantly tell whether that "something" is a *JSON document* or a *CouchDB instance* probably shouldn't be reading it anyway.

Note that **I** shouldn't be reading it, since I wouldn't have a clue what either of those things might look like. If OP thinks he might have any such readers (outside this ELU context), he should simply break it down into separate statements (or otherwise rephrase) as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Every five minutes, the Node.js application posts to my CouchDB instance a JSON document (which is) coded below:

```
:{ foo: bar,
key: 2
}
```